# GeoServer Image Mosaics: Queries on PostGIS index tables exceed max connection limit

Tags: geoserver

I have succesfully created 2 Geoserver ImageMosaics for time series rasters, with the index being a PostGIS database table, defined in the `datastore.properties` file. The optional parameters of the properties config file as such as `Connection\ timeout` and `max\ connections` are all left on default.

Now, I am running into issues with the availability of the raster layers, as the number of open connections from (what I assume is) the GeoServer instance to the database exceeds PostgreSQL's limit of 100 connections at a time.

Below is a partial readout of PostgreSQL's `pg_stat_activity;` to show the active connections to the database (some names replaced).

My question is, whether this reflects normal behaviour:

According to the `datastore.properties` default values, I would expect only 10 max connections for each ImgMosaic (here: 13 open connections for *image_mosaic_1*). Also, all connections are idle, sometimes for hours.

I am aware of the option to use JNDI for GeoServer connection pooling. But I'm unsure if this would rectify the issue, or if this indicates a faulty configuration of the ImgMosaics (or wrong understanding on my part).

**pg_stat_activity output (partial)**

| application_name | backend_start | query_start | state_change | wait_event_type | wait_event | state | query | backend_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:09:59 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:42:59 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:49 | 2021-11-02 15:00:49 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:42:33 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:42:59 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:24 | 2021-11-02 13:34:56 | 2021-11-02 13:34:56 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:07 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_1" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:19:58 | 2021-11-02 15:19:59 | 2021-11-02 15:19:59 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:06 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:06 | 2021-11-02 13:54:31 | 2021-11-02 13:54:31 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:19:59 | 2021-11-02 15:20:01 | 2021-11-02 15:20:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:06 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | Client | ClientRead | idle | SELECT min("time_stamp") FROM "image_mosaic_schema"."img_mosaic_2" WHERE ("time_stamp" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "time_stamp" > $3) | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:09:59 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:09:59 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:09:59 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:09:59 | 2021-11-02 13:34:50 | 2021-11-02 13:34:50 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:19:58 | 2021-11-02 15:20:01 | 2021-11-02 15:20:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:42 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | 2021-11-02 14:43:01 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | 2021-11-02 14:43:00 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:10:46 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:17:14 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | 2021-11-02 13:34:58 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:28:14 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | 2021-11-02 13:28:16 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | 2021-11-02 13:28:15 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:06 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:06 | 2021-11-02 13:54:33 | 2021-11-02 13:54:33 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 13:54:10 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | 2021-11-02 13:54:34 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:49 | 2021-11-02 15:00:49 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |
| PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 2021-11-02 15:00:42 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | 2021-11-02 15:00:48 | Client | ClientRead | idle | ROLLBACK | client backend |

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer uses a pool of Postgis connections so the number of open idle connections is normal.

If you have a slow Postgis server or other people are heavily using it, you can see time outs for requests, first make sure you have an index on your tile index table and that it is being used by the queries that GeoServer is making (these will appear in the log file if you turn logging up to `GEOSERVER-DEVELOPER`).

Failing that turn up the connection timeout from the default.